# show image instead of Alt text if image src not present

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using imageFlow as a base . but my problem is i want to show text on top of image this i tried doing but JS file don't Accept any div around img tag.

```
       <img src="" alt=""   >
```

is there any way to show alternate image if image src not able .

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below

```
 <div style="background: transparent url("tempballoon.png") no-repeat left top; font-size: 32px;width: 100%; height: height:[height of image]">
  Test
 </div>
```

Or can build as [given in this link](http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/)

Comment: What to do if he doesn't want to use the image as background.

Comment: @ManishJangir check the link given in the answer.

Comment: This would place text on top of an image even if the `src` is given, which doesn't sound like what OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="" alt="" style="postion:relative;">
<div style="postion:absolute;">Your image alt text</div>
```

Set the top,left,bottom and right postion of your div according to where you want to show the text.